# SwiftUI NavigationLink in ScrollView not responding until scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, scrollview, swiftui-navigationlink

As the title says, NavigationLink (or Button) does not receive tap before the horizontal scrollview has been scrolled, i.e. nothing is tappable/reponsive. After scrolling everything works as expected.

I am using Xcode 12 Beta 2 with the API of iOS 13 (can not use iOS 14 API due to the clients needs)

```
struct ARQuickMenuChooseArt: View {
let title: String
let favorites: [Artwork]
var donePressed: (() -> Void)?
var seeAllArtPressed: (() -> Void)?

var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 24) {
        Text("Favourites")
            .font(.title)
            .padding(.bottom, -10)
        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
            HStack(spacing: 12) {
                ForEach(favorites) { favorite in
                    NavigationLink(destination: Text("Destination View")) {
                        ARQuickMenuArtListItem(artwork: favorite)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Here is the view that uses the view containing the scrollview.

```
struct AddArtFlowView: View {
let controller: ARArtworksModelController
@Binding var position: CardPosition
@EnvironmentObject var appState: AppState
    
var body: some View {
    ARMenuContainer(position: $position, dismissAction: dismiss) {
        NavigationView {
            ARQuickMenuChooseArt(
                title: "Add artwork",
                favorites: artworkData,
                seeAllArtPressed: {
                    appState.activeView = .menuOpen(.add)
                }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

}

ARMenuContainer is simply a wrapper, seen here:

```
struct ARMenuContainer<Content>: View where Content: View {
@Binding var position: CardPosition
let dismissAction: () -> Void
let content: () -> Content

init(position: Binding<CardPosition>, dismissAction: @escaping () -> Void, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) {
    self._position = position
    self.dismissAction = dismissAction
    self.content = content
}

var body: some View {
    SlideOverCard($position, backgroundTapped: dismissAction) {
        VStack {
            content()
            
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding(.top, -3)
    }
}
```

}

Which in turn uses a SlideOverCard https://github.com/moifort/swiftUI-slide-over-card, which is used to display above an AR experience.

Here is how it looks in-app
[image]

Any ideas why it will not respond without first scrolling?